# Example with soft-coding

Tags: php, mysql

What is difference between "hard-coding" and "soft-coding"?
Please explain it with an example of `PHP` code and MYSQL.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hard-coding simply means that the value of a variable is inserted directly in the source code like `$variable = "value";` whereas soft-coding means that values are loaded from an external file, database or stream of some description like: `$variable = file_get_contents('path/to/value/of/variable');`

Answer (score 0):

I googled it.

Check this out: http://www.thoughtclusters.com/2007/08/hard-coding-and-soft-coding/